# Playing audio file while I download it

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I am trying to play partially downloaded file (I want the audio to start when it has enough downloaded data).

I have tried the following:

```
self.mutableData = nil;
self.mutableData = [NSMutableData data];
self.mutableData.length = 0;

GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher =
[[self driveService].fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:song.filePath];

[fetcher setReceivedDataBlock:^(NSData *dataReceivedSoFar) {
    [self.mutableData appendData:dataReceivedSoFar];

    if (!self.audioPlayer.playing && self.mutableData.length > 1000000)
    {
        self.audioPlayer = nil;
        self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:self.mutableData error:nil];
        [self.audioPlayer play];
    }
}];

[fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) 
    {
        NSLog(@"NSURLResponse: %@", fetcher.response.);
    } 
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

But it starts playing the first 1-3 seconds and then the app either crashes or it plays that 1-3 seconds over and over again until the download finishes and then it plays the whole song.

Can I somehow achieve this with `AVPlayer`, or fix this problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have a stream of `Data` to play before download finishes but I can't figure it out. xD

Answer (score 1):

AVAudioPlayer cannot play files that are open for writing / downloading, but AVPlayer can. Switch to AVPlayer.

Comment: This answer is lacking in details, but I don't think it warrants deletion... it is better than nothing, isn't it?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare There isn't nothing though. It's a poor quality copy of the other answer posted a year beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

To stream audio, you should use [AVPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [Audio Queue Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

`initWithData` isn't intended for this purpose. You can use `initWithData` after you have downloaded the entire file.

Comment: Ok I know, but what if I cannot obtain a direct link to stream? This is the problem with google drive, so my other solution is to start download to device, and then start playing from it. Do you have any advice?